# setFrame crop window

Tags: objective-c, nswindow, cut, borderless

I have a window that should have dynamic height.
I have drawn the window in the Interface Builder, and after the calculations in code I try to set the height.
It should be also on the same position on the desktop.
I use the following code to do that.

```
[myWin setFrame:NSMakeRect(myWin.frame.origin.x,
                       myWin.frame.origin.y - (yPos+2*MARGIN_CONST - myWin.frame.size.height),
                       myWin.frame.size.width, 
                       yPos+2*MARGIN_CONST)
 display:YES];
```

The window is a borderless window.
When I print the frame before and after, it seems as it has taken the new values, but the window is cut from the top and it has the same height as before (now I see the controlls on the bottom of the window, but those on the top are cut).
Any ideas?

Thank you very much.

Comment: do you want to change only height?

Comment: you might be setting the y origin as a negative or invalid value.

Comment: Yes, the height and the yPos (in order to stay the window on the same position as previously). When I print the new frame, the Y position is as expected

Comment: I solved the problem by setting the AutoresizingMask (in the Interface Builder) of the Window's ContentView to MinX, MaxX, MinY, MaxY.